# How to call class file method which has defined as void in mainfom?

Tags: c#, function, winforms, class, methods

I have one (form) and one (class file). but i've wrote that function as void it becomes a void and not working on the form. i Don't know how to change it.

(in C# winforms app.)

## colors.cs

```
class Colors
    {
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        public IEnumerable<Control> Controls { get; private set; }

        public void themecolor()
        {

            foreach (Control c in mainForm.Controls)
            {
                bool Button = false;

                if ((Button ))
                {
                    
                    c.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    c.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    c.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    c.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Mainform.cs

```
 
            switch (id)
            {
                case 1:
                    Colors cr = new Colors();
                    cr.themecolor();
                    MovePnl(btnHome);
                    Lbltitle.Text = "HOME";
                    panel3.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Colors opens Mainform and Mainform opens Colors? Not sure if that's a good idea. What is a class file method? From what we see, Mainform does not have any methods at all. Maybe you want to create a [mre]

Comment: I cannot see any sense in your design and code. You should focus more on that.

Answer (score 0):

For the example that you want, your `MainForm` should only have one instance and you should pass that instance to the `Colors` class. Also your type check for button isn't correct

```
class Colors
{
    public void themecolor(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        foreach (Control c in mainForm.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Button)
            {
                c.BackColor = Color.Red;
                c.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                c.BackColor = Color.Green;
                c.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then from MainForm, you pass itself to the function using `this` keyword:

```
Colors cr = new Colors();
cr.themecolor(this);
```

Comment: if(c is Button){...}

Comment: This doesn't consider Controls that are child of other Containers, e.g., a GroupBox